# Get filenames only from full path

Tags: ant

I am using an Ant script to get the contents of a directory by means of the following:

```
<ac:foreach target="process-test" param="the_file" delimiter=",">
    <path>
        <fileset dir="${test.suite.url}">
            <include name="**/*.html"/>
            <exclude name="**/cases/"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>
</ac:foreach>
```

This is returning the full path to the file (which is something I also need) but, is it possible to strip away the path and give me just the filename?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Isn't the Ant [`<basename>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html) the thing you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for this.  Im new to Ant so this is exceptionally helpful.  Thank you very much.